# IR light transmittance through body

Tags: visible-light, refraction, infrared-radiation

I was watching this youtube video : https://youtu.be/aa_tCzIMJjE
and i was wondering why the IR light that goes through his hand spreads and mainly shows surface features like his veins and not the bones inside like an xray would instead.IR radiation penetrates the human body easily
[image]

He has removed the ir filter from a camera btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a flash light and go to a dark room. Cover the flashlight with your palm and light it. You  will see the same as with the infrared light in the video. It the same effect, with strong enough light, either infrared or visible, our flesh is partially transparent and the light defuses  and outlines the veins, as blood is less transparent.

It is not like [an x-ray](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-x-ray-normal-human-hands-front-on-black-background-77380075.html)

[image: xray]

The X-rays are not diffused through the flesh of the hand. Due to their larger energy, smaller wavelength they scatter through, illuminating bones that can absorb them much more that flesh, and blood. Note that veins behave the same as flesh for these wavelengths.